# Linq To Entities (MySql) field lazy loading and/or projection problem

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq To Entities so I can Linq to my MySql database.  My problem is that I've got a table with large text fields, so I don't want to load them unless I need them, and the L2E lazy loading model doesn't work because (1) the MySql provider doesn't seem to support lazy loading at all, and (2) even if it did, I don't think it would be correct anyway.

Stripped down to illustrate the problem, I have a large table with columns:
Id, Text1, Text2, Text3

I'll have a routine that needs to work only with Text1, and a different routine that works with Text2.  Because the contents of the text fields are large, I really don't want to select the text fields I'm not using for a given routine.

In other words, doing this would be too expensive:

```
Dim items = From i In db.MyTable Where [predicate]
```

But doing this:

```
Dim items = From i In db.MyTable Where [predicate] Select i.Id, i.Text1
```

creates an IQueryable(Of anonymous_type), instead of an IQueryable(Of MyTable), and since I need to be able to update various fields and call SaveChanges, I need MyTable objects to do this.  I can't convert the anonymous type to a new MyTable because the DataContext wouldn't know about it and thus updates wouldn't work.

(And it seems to me (though this may be my lack of L2E knowledge), that *even if* the MySql provider supported lazy loading, that would mean that I could specify lazy loading for the Text fields, but then it would make N queries to the server as I looped through N records.  In other words, lazy loading seems to be for when you might but probably won't need a big data column, not for when you *know* you want that column, but you don't want the other columns.)

So the question is: how can I select only the fields I want while still getting an object of the right type so that I can update it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really solved the problem as stated, but I've since found some reasonable workarounds, so I thought I'd mention them in case anyone else runs into this.

The first is simply to factor the large text fields into their own table in the database, and then have a separate entity for that table.  This happened to make sense for my application, because I had to do it anyway, but it would be annoying to change your database structure just to make some tool happy.

The other thing you could do is to select only the fields you want, but then project back into the table type instead of using an anonymous type, leaving out the fields you don't want.  That is, instead of this:

```
Dim items = From i In db.MyTable Where [predicate] Select i.Id, i.Text1
```

do this:

```
Dim items = From i In db.MyTable Where [predicate] Select New TableObject With {.Id = i.Id, .Text1 = i.Text1}
```

Then, if you do want to get the large text fields, ask for them explicitly in a separate query.

This is slightly irritating in that you have to explicitly populate the fields, but it's better than the original problem and I'm sure there's a way to improve upon this further.